# magento remove sku number (unit) from transactionnal email

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2. I have tried to remove sku from the transactional email when order is placed. After lot of r & d I got the solution. I removed the 
"`<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>`"
 line from 
"`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items.phtml`" 
and also removed "`<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>`"
 from "`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml`"
 but nothing helped. Just able to remove sku column from header from the `items.phtml` file.  I come to know to conclusion that the rows for the items generated are from `items.phtml` & these are -

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
    <tbody<?php echo $i%2 ? ' bgcolor="#F6F6F6"' : '' ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

only "`echo $this->getItemHtml($_item)`" this line is responcible to print all the columns. I’ve tried tracking the getItemHtml call back through all the code but still haven’t a clue where the actual table html gets generated from. Does anyone have clue?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Just tried your solution, you have made it in the right templates. This must work. Do you use a custom design package, where the default.phtml could have been overwritten?

Comment: no, i am just using only default template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already added one additional column in transactional emails.  The files mentioned by you is correct.  I think you have done in base/default folder.  If you have used any themes, then change the same in the path `app/design/frontend/default/yourThemeName/template`.